# how to update data without removing old data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to develop a database of the hotel, I have created two tables; one is `Room` and the second one is `Customer`.

Can I create a relationship between them that have updating data on the room table, which means every time a new customer. But the other table is for store customers data without removing old customers? For example:

**Room Table:**

```
Room_Id  | available | Customer_Id |
101      | Yes       |0            |
102      | Yes       |0            |
103      | No        | 1236        |
104      | No        | 1237        |
105      | No        | 1235        |
201      | No        | 1234        |
202      | No        | 1233        |
```

**After updating room table:**

```
Room_Id  | available | Customer_Id |
101      | No        | 1111        |
102      | No        | 2222        |
103      | Yse       | 0           |
104      | Yse       | 0           |
105      | Yse       | 0           |
201      | Yse       | 0           |
202      | Yse       | 0           |
```

**Customer Table should store both data:**

```
Customer_Id |
1111        |
2222        |
1236        |
1237        |
1235        |
1234        |
1233        |
```

I want something like this because when I try to update the room table, it also updates the customer table.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to achieve..update without removing old is confusing...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by some of what you've written. Showing us the code you used which caused the problem would be helpful. It would also help a lot to show us what result you wanted your query to achieve instead.

Comment: The question is unclear. SQL Server, or any database, won't update other tables unless you tell it to. What SQL command did you use? What is the *actual* script of those tables? Are you using cascading updates perhaps? Or triggers?

Comment: P.S. I'd say an obvious flaw in this design, if it's for a hotel, is that it has no concept of time. Again it's not 100% clear from your description, but it sounds like you want to keep records of previous bookings maybe? If so then your room availability table needs to include the start and end date of each booking. For this you'd need a 3rd table between Room and Customer, probably called Bookings. So you'd remove the "available" and "customer id" fields from the Room table, and instead the Bookings table would contain room id, customer id, start date, end date.

Comment: If you want to preserve previous assignments the best option is to use [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server 2016 and later. After any modifications the previous data will appear in History table. You can easily ask for data at a specific point in time with eg `FROM [dbo].[Department]
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2015-09-01 T10:00:00.7230011'`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, yes I mean updating the room table and without removing the customer table.
I used SQL Server as shown in tags.
By normal relationship will removing achieve in customer table or breaking the relationship

Comment: Sorry but I think maybe you need to find someone to help you translate into English, because it is hard to understand exactly what you mean in your comment.

Comment: No need, your solution is perfect. I created the 3rd table and it is work. Thank you @ADyson

Comment: oh I see. That wasn't clear from your previous comment. That's great, I'm glad it helped you.